# Disable image button on Pager Template in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I work in ASP.NET c# and MySQL database.

In my gridView I have added this code pagination.

```
    <PagerTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/bot_back_1.gif"
            CommandArgument="First" CommandName="Page" Visible="true" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/bot_back.gif"
            CommandArgument="Prev" CommandName="Page" Visible="true" />
        Page
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPages" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="ddl_Class"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
        of
<asp:Label ID="lblPageCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/bot_next.gif"
            CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page" Visible="true" />
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/bot_next_1.gif"
            CommandArgument="Last" CommandName="Page" Visible="true" />
    </PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Visible="true" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ImageUrl="/Images/Add_button.gif" />
```

Now I need to set as visible false all the content on PagerTemplate when is activate :

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    gvProducts.ShowFooter = true;
    btnAdd.Visible = false;        
    BindData();        
}
```

I have tried with :

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    gvProducts.ShowFooter = true;
    btnAdd.Visible = false;  
    ImageButton1.Visible = false;  
    BindData();        
}
```

But I have error :

> CS0103: The name 'ImageButton1' does not exist in the current context.

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use the method `FindControl()` to determine the Control

```
ImageButton btn =  (ImageButton)gvProducts.BottomPagerRow.FindControl("ImageButton1");
btn.Visible = false;
```